# External CSS not working with Github Pages

Tags: html, github

I have a web host on GitHub Pages (http://evancase54.github.io), and I'm trying to link to an external CSS file, which is one folder from the root.

Trying it in this way and it does not work:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css">`
and I'm not sure how I am supposed to do it.

`index.css` is located in a folder called `styles`, and it's saying that apparently it's not found. I don't know the issue that's being caused here, so if someone could help me with this, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. I apparently wasn't using the root `/`, so it looked like `styles/index.css` instead of `/styles/index.css`

Answer (score 1):

The path is case sensitive,

`Styles/index.css` should work

or you can rename it to lower case.

Comment: I found the fix, and it wasn't that. I apparently wasn't using the root /, so it looked like `styles/index.css` instead of `/styles/index.css`