# css not working for github pages

Tags: css, github-pages

my css is not working correctly on my github page. This is my [repo](https://github.com/AbradolfLinclr/AbradolfLinclr.github.io). This is my [website](http://abradolflinclr.github.io). I created this portfolio website without Github pages and it works correctly. I am very new to github , so there is a good chance I'm missing something. I usually localize all my css/jscript but for simplicity reasons I changed all my css/javascript to the html link.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\main.css">


</head>
```

Comment: Please inline relevant code here so the question is easier to answer, and will receive higher engagement.

Comment: sorry about that. code added.

Comment: It looks like Github is still tracking your initial commit.  How are you making your nexxt few commits?

Comment: I got pretty confused when using git bash, so i switched over to git for windows. I've been updating locally. Committing locally and syncing afterwards

Comment: Are you doing a push after commit?

Comment: I use sync, pushing the changes locally to the master. Is there a way to troubleshoot what is going wrong?

Comment: css\main.css - back slash works fine?

Comment: oops, thank you. Still doesn't fix the problem I'm having unfortunately

Comment: @karthick any ideas?

Comment: It looks like Git is still not taking your latest change. Can yo go to command line and type git commit -m 'test' and then  type git push

Comment: wait for 10 mins. And then refresh your page

Comment: there is nothing for me to commit

Comment: I see you are trying to change the current HEAD on your repo, I will say remove the ./css/bootstrapX.X.X as that is what is complaining about you [REPO](https://github.com/AbradolfLinclr/AbradolfLinclr.github.io/commits/master)

Comment: Another thing will be to change your framework to Foundation6 check my [WIP REPO](https://github.com/T04435/Me) and [WIP SITE](https://t04435.github.io/Me/)

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv Thank You! It works! Could you explain the error of that bootstrap issue?

Comment: like @TarasYaremkiv mentioned remove your ./css/bootstrap folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my HTML file and my CSS file. I fixed it like this:

1. I had a repo with the index.html and a folder call "style" with the style.css file in it.
2. Deploy my index.html with the link tag within the head tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Pay attention to the href attribute: "./style/style.css".

Andy.-

Answer (score 0):

Like @TarasYaremkiv mentioned remove your './css/bootstrap-3.3.7/' folder.

The reason why it's happening is because Jekyll engine is looking for the includes present in the file 'bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/components.html'

For example: this file {% include components/glyphicons.html %} is not present in the components directory of your bootstrap folder. Hence the error.

You can avoid these kind of error's by downloading only the necessary compiled files or use cdn links

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\main.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
```

original post -  [External CSS not working with Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495510/external-css-not-working-with-github-pages)